# webview_flutter: Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Write permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, webview-flutter

Expected behavior:
Copy text using `Copy to clipboard` from a website

Behavior:
It throws the following error and text is not copied to android's Clipbord.

Package: webview_flutter

```
I/chromium(12065): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Write permission denied.", source: ..url (0)
```

sample code:

```
WebView(
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     initialUrl: url,
  )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you dind the solution?

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77136763/13898059