# Flutter InAppWebView throwing error Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Write permission denied. when tested on Android devices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

**Objective**

- I am trying to copy a text from a copy button inside a web page. The copy function itself is working fine when i open it using chrome, firefox and safari browser

**Expected behavior:**
After pressing the copy button, the text is copied into phone clipboard.
**Current behavior:**
After pressing the copy button, Flutter InAppWebView throwing error Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Write permission denied.

**Step done to fix this error**

1. I have added android permission inside my Project > android > app > src > main >AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2. PermissionRequestResponseAction is set to .GRANT, however, this callback is not called when i press on the copy button inside the web page

```
    androidOnPermissionRequest: (webViewController, origin, resources) async {
                      return PermissionRequestResponse(
                        resources: resources,
                        action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
                      );
                    },
```

3. javaScriptEnabled is set to true for Android, and its true by default

```
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          // allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
          // javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
          // allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));
```

Here are some related issue that have been asked, but still no solution for it:

1. [webview_flutter: Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Write permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892996/webview-flutter-uncaught-in-promise-notallowederror-write-permission-denied)
2. https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/678

How to solve for this error? Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i also face this issue so i was resolve it by this way:

- i was try to add permission for android but it still not work and then i change to use java script to solve it maybe u can see it:

```dart
InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(url)),
        onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
          controller
            ..evaluateJavascript(
              source:
                  "document.getElementById('unwanted-element').remove();",
            )
            ..evaluateJavascript(
              source:
                  "document.body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(45deg, #3D1912, #701D1B)';",
            )
            ..evaluateJavascript(
                source:
                    'javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText = (msg) => { return window.flutter_inappwebview?.callHandler("android", msg); }');
        },
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            handleCopyText(controller, context, 'android');
          } else {
            handleCopyText(controller, context, 'copyText');
          }
        },
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              disableVerticalScroll: true, disableHorizontalScroll: true),
        ),
      );
```

and then u can listen callback from webview to catch your text and save it to clipboard

Comment: Please integrate your code as part of your answer rather than via a link to a screenshot.  To do this, refer to the section **Code Blocks** on [the help page for formatting on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the proper solution to handle such cases is what [@ThanhOP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16184525/thanhop) mentioned, The only fix that is working is to handle that with JS injection.
Register a channel to get the data and send It to the FLutter side.

Note: I deleted extra code and added the required ones.
It works like a charm even with websites that had no problem.

onLoadStop property looks like this:

```
    onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
  controller.evaluateJavascript(
      source:
          'javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText = (msg) => { return window.flutter_inappwebview?.callHandler("axs-wallet-copy-clipboard", msg); }');
  controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
    handlerName: 'axs-wallet-copy-clipboard',
    callback: (args) {
      copy(args);
    },
  );
},
```

copy function looks like this:

```
  void copy(List<dynamic> params) {
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: params[0]));
}
```