# Copy to clipboard not working on Inappwebview_flutter

Tags: android, flutter

> Samsung SV03 , Android 10
> When I test the copy to clipboard, clicking the copy button and exiting to paste the copied text into Google Chrome, it doesn't work. However, it works well on iOS

I want the copy to clipboard feature to work well on Android's WebView.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/77136763/13898059.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem now.