# flutter inappwebview android permission API NotAllowedError: Write permission denied

Tags: android, flutter, webview, clipboard

| **flutter_inappwebview version** | **6.0.0-beta.24+1** |
| --- | --- |
| Flutter version | 3.10.4 |
| Android version | 13 |

We copy text on the web using Navigator.clipboard.writeText.
It works well with iOS, but the following error appears in AOS.

Error Message
`(android) WebView ID {{webviewID}} calling "onConsoleMessage" using {messageLevel: 3, message: NotAllowedError: Write permission denied.}`

I think It's not related to android OS permission. We allowed external storage permission on androidManifest and still this issue happened.

I found out that web permission API(navigation) does not support Android WebView.

How can I handle this trouble? Do I have to open more permission to WebView or JavaScript?

Success copying text on android webview.

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77136763/13898059

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, `"NotAllowedError: Write permission denied,"` typically occurs when you're trying to perform a write operation from a `WebView` in `Android`, but the WebView's security settings prevent it from doing so. This is a security feature to protect the user's device and data.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

**1 Check Permissions** : You mentioned that you've allowed external storage permission in your AndroidManifest, but this issue is likely related to WebView's permission system, not the Android permissions. Ensure that you have the necessary WebView permissions set up correctly.

**2 WebView Settings** : Configure the WebView settings to allow the write operation. You can do this in your Flutter app code:

```
InAppWebView(
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      permissions: <String, dynamic>{
        'clipboardWrite': 'true',
      },
    ),
  ),
  // Other WebView configurations
)
```

In the code above, we explicitly set the clipboardWrite permission to true for Android WebView. This should allow the write operation to the clipboard.

**1 JavaScript Permissions** : If the above steps don't work, it's possible that the JavaScript code within the WebView is trying to access the clipboard and is getting blocked. You can try to explicitly grant JavaScript access to the clipboard:

```
InAppWebView(
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
        JavascriptChannel(
          name: 'clipboard',
          onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
            // Handle clipboard operations here
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  // Other WebView configurations
)
```

In your JavaScript code running in the WebView, you can then use the clipboard JavaScript channel to communicate with the Flutter app to perform clipboard operations.

**1 Update WebView** : Ensure you are using an `up-to-date version` of the `InAppWebView package` as WebView behaviour and permissions can change with updates.
If none of these solutions work, please provide more information about your code and WebView configuration so that I can assist you further. Additionally, it's essential to keep in mind that clipboard access from a WebView is subject to security restrictions, and some actions may not be permitted for security reasons.

Comment: Hi, Sparsh :) Thank you for your solutions. I tried permission check but still failed. We are using the latest version of flutter_inappwebview so AndroidInAppWebViewOptions and permissions are deprecated.